# referencing another type in xml schema

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:ns2="urn:uRServerResponse" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  xmlns:ns1="SBE"  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" >
  <types>
    <xs:schema xmlns="SBE" targetNamespace="SBE">
      <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <xs:complexType name="SBEOrder">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="OrderGUID" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="BuyerGUID" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="PONumber" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="Date_Submitted" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element name="Date_Shipped" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element name="Date_Received" type="xs:dateTime" />
          <xs:element name="ItemCount" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element name="ActionCount" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns="urn:uRServerResponse" targetNamespace="urn:uRServerResponse">
      <xs:import namespace="SBE"/>
      <xs:complexType name="TSBEServerResponseBase">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="TSBEServerResponse">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xs:extension base="ns2:TSBEServerResponseBase">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="SBEOrder" type="ns1:SBEOrder"/>
              <xs:element name="ItemClassCount" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="ItemClassHistoryCount" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="ItemClassInfoCount" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="InvoiceCount" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </types>
</definitions>
```

When I have the above section validate, I got Type `'SBE:SBEOrder'` is not declared.
What am I missing in the above declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I actually think that your problem lies in the import declaration for the SOAPENC schema:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
```

which is making the first schema invalid, causing the second schema to be unable to reference its types.

Skip that import statement and you should be ok. :)

**Edit: (to add code)**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns1 = "SBE" xmlns:ns2 = "urn:uRServerResponse" xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
<types>    
    <xs:schema targetNamespace = "SBE" xmlns = "SBE">      
        <xs:complexType name = "SBEOrder">        
            <xs:sequence>          
                <xs:element name = "OrderGUID" type = "xs:string"/>          
                <xs:element name = "BuyerGUID" type = "xs:string"/>          
                <xs:element name = "PONumber" type = "xs:string"/>          
                <xs:element name = "Status" type = "xs:string"/>          
                <xs:element name = "Date_Submitted" type = "xs:dateTime"/>          
                <xs:element name = "Date_Shipped" type = "xs:dateTime"/>          
                <xs:element name = "Date_Received" type = "xs:dateTime"/>          
                <xs:element name = "ItemCount" type = "xs:int"/>          
                <xs:element name = "ActionCount" type = "xs:int"/>        
            </xs:sequence>      
        </xs:complexType>    
    </xs:schema>    
    <xs:schema targetNamespace = "urn:uRServerResponse" xmlns = "urn:uRServerResponse">      
        <xs:complexType name = "TSBEServerResponseBase">        
            <xs:sequence>        </xs:sequence>      
        </xs:complexType>      
        <xs:complexType name = "TSBEServerResponse">        
            <xs:complexContent mixed = "false">          
                <xs:extension base = "ns2:TSBEServerResponseBase">            
                    <xs:sequence>              
                        <xs:element name = "SBEOrder" type = "ns1:SBEOrder"/>              
                        <xs:element name = "ItemClassCount" type = "xs:int"/>              
                        <xs:element name = "ItemClassHistoryCount" type = "xs:int"/>              
                        <xs:element name = "ItemClassInfoCount" type = "xs:int"/>              
                        <xs:element name = "InvoiceCount" type = "xs:int"/>            
                    </xs:sequence>          
                </xs:extension>        
            </xs:complexContent>      
        </xs:complexType>    
    </xs:schema>  
</types>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Removing the above import statement does not make any difference. The import statement is required for another element which I removed to simplify my problem. Do you have another suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: In a wsdl don't need to import the namespaces in each schema, you can simply declare them in the definitions element. The code I have ended with, seems to work fine. (see my editted answer for complete xml code). If that still does not work for you, maybe you should give me the complete version of your problem.

Comment: I understand your point and I agree with it. However the XML checker keeps on complaining.  I am using visual studio 2013. I copied your version into a new XML file and added </definitions> to the end. I got 2 warnings and 1 message
Warning 10 Type 'SBE:SBEOrder' is not declared. XMLFile1.xml 27 9 Miscellaneous Files
Warning 11 Namespace 'SBE' is not available to be referenced in this schema. XMLFile1.xml 27 9 Miscellaneous Files
Message 12 Namespace 'SBE' is not available to be referenced in this schema. XMLFile1.xml 27 9 Miscellaneous Files

Comment: It seems that it is a bug in visual studio 2013. If I break the schema SBE portion into a .xsd file and then import SBE with schemalocation, visual studio won't complain about SBE:SBEOrder not found